# Using signalR in asp.net core, how do I change the userID convention to use the users email address instead of default userId?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

Im using

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core" Version="1.1.0" />
```

in an asp.net core web api. I can see by default that if I want to send a specific user a message I can call a method such as

```
_hub.Clients.User("c5MOTEmXsEZjoVf-y_sVQD_g-yBis9fvLMbyNJX3M31").SendAsync("MessageUpdated", "ee");
```

However, I would like to know, is there any way to change this such that I can instead pass in a different value for the userId?

For example, users email address instead?

Is this even possible?

Also, is it possible to detect what the userId is if I have a users email address? Perhaps this second question might help me solve my particular problem better.

Answer (score 0):

In definition of `User(string userId)` and `Users(IReadOnlyList<string> userIds)`, we can find it accepts user ID(s).

[image]

> is it possible to detect what the userId is if I have a users email address?

If you'd like to send message(s) to specific user(s) based on users email or name etc, you can try to maintain the mapping of user's email to userId(s) or connections, then you can get userId(s) dynamically and send message(s) to specific user(s).

To achieve it, you can refer to the following sample.

```
private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> NtoIdMappingTable = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
{
    await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
}

public async Task SendPrivateMessage(string user, string receiver, string message)
{
    var userId = NtoIdMappingTable.GetValueOrDefault(receiver);

    await Clients.Users(userId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, $"{ message}(Private Mes)");
}

public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    var username = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    var userId = Context.UserIdentifier;
    List<string> userIds;

    if (!NtoIdMappingTable.TryGetValue(username, out userIds))
    {
        userIds = new List<string>();
        userIds.Add(userId);

        NtoIdMappingTable.Add(username, userIds);
    }
    else
    {
        userIds.Add(userId);
    }

    await base.OnConnectedAsync();
}

//other code logic
```

Note: *above sample (maintain user's email and userId(s) information in a dictionary) is just for testing purpose, in your project, you can maintain user's email and userId(s) information in other data store/storage you want.*

*Test Result:*

[image]

Comment: This is helpful. However, not sure if this helps me exactly since I need to invoke _smsHub.Clients.User() outside of the hub class, say, somewhere in application services.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding is how Context.UserIdentifier is set. If application layer server side needs to send a message to a user, how is the code supposed to obtain a list of user identifiers? Am i literally supposed to persist all user identifiers on OnConnectedAsync? I seems somewhat strange to me that I have to rely on persisting the set of identifiers myself. I understand based on your example above that a client can manually input a target receiver.But how can server side code in app services for example determine the acceptable values of receiver/userID?

Comment: for example, suppose I have a controller and the controller knows a users email address. How can the controller send the message only to the user based on email alone? I can see that 1 solution may be to persist user email + identifier OnConnectedAsync into a repo, then use the repo in the controller to obtain user identifier. Is that the only way? Is there not some other way though so that I dont have to write all the persistance code + maintain a DB table with that information?

Comment: I'm starting to read more about this. It sounds like I'm not the only 1 that wishes for a list of all users in a class maintained within the library itself.I'm hoping to find out if this is a feature request in the library so that I can avoid having to write code myself. :/

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

Update

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

to include

```
services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameUserIdProvider>();
```

with

```
public class NameUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
    {
        return connection.User?.Identity?.Name;
    }
}
```

Now use can user email address in

```
_hub.Clients.User(userEmail).SendAsync
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works, I'm trying what you have here and can't get it to work.