# Change Default User Identifier for SignalR Connections

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

The SignalR docs state "By default, SignalR uses the ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier from the ClaimsPrincipal associated with the connection as the user identifier."  I'd like to change that default behavior and I'm not sure where to change the setting.  Specifically, I just want to use the user's login name (they are logged in via Identity).

There doesn't seem to be an suitable option (that I'm seeing) for .AddSignalR() and I don't see anything promising on the client-side, such as when the connection is created.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59316904/11398810) resolve your issue?

Comment: I've done my best to implement it, it was pretty straight-forward, but I see no change is behavior.